# What's the shortest way to see if all the elements are not nil?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Is there a more direct way to do this?

```
[1, nil, 2, 'a'].all? {|x| x}
```

Comment: Wow, I would say that's pretty direct!

Comment: Short and performant, even if it's not terribly verbose. Not going to do better than this.

Comment: What does your `all? {|x| x}` approach do with `[1, false, 'fish', :bicycle]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is the [`any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500) or [`none?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001502) methods, and using the [`nil?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001007) method:

```
irb(main):005:0> [1, nil, 2, 'a'].any?(&:nil?)
=> true
irb(main):006:0> [1, nil, 2, 'a'].none?(&:nil?)
=> false
```

The `&:foo` syntax works to replace anything like: `list.each() {|x| x.foo()}`

Comment: Nice, these line up with dan's intent and saying exactly what you mean is a good policy.

Comment: @mu is too short, heh, I liked the directness of your `.include?` method; the leading `!` might be easy to overlook in this specific case, but with a variable, it should stand out well enough.

Comment: In rails projects you also have blank? and present? to work with.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000265) and add a "not" to the beginning:

```
![1, nil, 2, 'a'].include?(nil)
```

If all elements are non-nil then the array does not include `nil`. Using `.all?` means that you have to scan the entire array, `.include?` should stop as soon as it finds a match and there's no overhead of calling a block; so, `.include?` should be quicker but the performance differences will probably be pretty irrelevant unless you have a massive array. I'd go with whichever one reads best for you.

Comment: This will likely be a bit faster than my answer.

Comment: @Douglas: The performance differences are almost certainly going to be irrelevant. I actually like sarnold's as far as clarity goes, using `none?` exactly matches the intent and clarity is usually my first choice.

Answer (score 4):

Are you playing Golf?

That's about as short and direct as you are gonna get.  Personally I'd prefer a slightly more verbose way:

```
[...].all? {|x| !x.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do::

```
!list.any?(&:nil?)
```

But I find that less direct than your original code.  Fewer characters, though, and if you dislike blocks this hides the block in the &:symbol

[Well, your original code has a problem which is that {|x| x } evaluates as false for both nil and false values.  If you really want the block {|x| !x.nil?} ]

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as mu is too short, and I don't think mine any better than it, but just another variant:

```
![1, nil, 2, 'a'].index(nil)
```